Mixing Task with Future Publisher in Swift 6 with strict concurrency checking
I implemented a method that returns a Future (a Combine Publisher), which produces a value (or error) from a Task, it works in Swift 5:
  func call(api: API) -> AnyPublisher<Data?, Error> {

    return Future { promise in

      Task {
        let response = await AF.request( ... ).serializingData().response 

          if let error = response.error {
            promise(.failure(error))
          } else {
            promise(.success(response.data))
          }

      }

    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()

  }

The above code could not compile in Swift 6 with strict concurrency checking, because promise is NOT a sendable type:
Capture of 'promise' with non-sendable type '(Result<Data?, any Error>) -> Void' in a `@Sendable` closure
Does this mean with Swift 6, it is no longer possible to have a Combine publisher that produce value from an asynchronous method?
I checked Apple's documentation Using Combine for Your App’s Asynchronous Code, but it does not mention how to mix Combine and Task with strict concurrency checking.

Why do you need a future at all, why not rewrite the function to only use async/await?

Unrelated but why is Data? optional at all? The goal of the Result type is to return non-optional types in both success and failure cases. Apart from that I agree with Joakim, drop Combine in favor of async/await.

I understand that it would be better rewriting this method to adopt async/await. For now I am looking for an intermediate solution so my project can adopt Swift 6 without rewriting lots of code.

FWIW, merely wrapping a Task {…} in a Future results in a task that will not be canceled when the future is canceled. I would advise creating a custom future that will cancel its associated Task for you when the future is canceled. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78899940/1271826. Bottom line, whenever you employ unstructured concurrency, make sure you handle cancelation.

I believe the lack of a @Sendable annotation on Future.Promise is a bug, as I believe it is supposed to be thread-safe. You could file a feedback report with Apple.
For now, you can work around it using the Swift 6 nonisolated(unsafe) syntax to tell the compiler not to worry about it:
func call() -> AnyPublisher<Data?, Error> {
    return Future { promise in

        // Copy promise to a local property to make it nonisolated(unsafe):
        nonisolated(unsafe) let promise = promise

        Task {
            // Now capture promise in a Sendable closure.

            promise(.success(Data()))
        }
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}


If you want to fix it for Xcode15 / iOS17 too you need to use wrapper:
fileprivate final class FutureResultWrapper<Output, Failure: Error>: @unchecked Sendable {
    fileprivate typealias Promise = (Result<Output, Failure>) -> Void

    fileprivate let completionResult: Promise

    /// Creates a publisher that invokes a promise closure when the publisher emits an element.
    ///
    /// - Parameter attemptToFulfill: A ``Future/Promise`` that the publisher invokes when the publisher emits an element or terminates with an error.
    fileprivate init(_ attemptToFulfill: @escaping Promise) {
        self.completionResult = attemptToFulfill
    }
}

and then use it like this:
    let publisher = Future<T, Never> { [weak self] completionResult in
    guard let self = self else {
        completionResult(.success(object))
        return
    }

    let wrapper = FutureResultWrapper<T, Never>(completionResult)

    Task.detached { [weak self] in
        await self?.persist(object)
        wrapper.completionResult(.success(object))
    }

